# Cloud Functions using wildcard path don't work

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to update all documents in a collection with a Cloud Function. With this code it worked for updating one document (with the id 0) in the collection releasedQuestions:

```
exports.decreaseQuestionRestDuration = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   const test = admin.firestore().doc('releasedQuestions/0').update({restDuration: 42})
        .then(snapshot => {
            response.send(0)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            response.status(500).send(error)
        })
});
```

but when i will update all documents in the collection with a wildcard path like this:

```
const test = admin.firestore().doc('releasedQuestions/{qid}').update({restDuration: 42})
```

it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

My Cloud Firestore structure is this:
[Cloud Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cauGp.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard path syntax you are using (i.e. `doc('releasedQuestions/{qid}')`) can only be used in Cloud Functions **definition**, when, for example, you define a Cloud Firestore trigger by specifying a document path and an event type, as follows:

```
exports.useWildcard = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {...});
```

In your case you are actually calling the [`doc()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#doc) method, for which the `documentPath` parameter shall be a `string`. This is why it works in the first case but not in the second one (there isn't any Firestore document with ID `{qid}` in your collection).

---

If you want, in your HTTP Cloud Function, to update all the docs of a collection, you could use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0#batched-writes), as follows:

```
exports.decreaseQuestionRestDuration = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const db = admin.firestore();

    db.collection('releasedQuestions').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            let batch = db.batch();
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                batch.update(doc.ref, { restDuration: 42 });
            });
            return batch.commit()
        })
        .then(() => {
            response.send(0)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            response.status(500).send(error)
        })

});
```

---

Note however, that a batched write can contain up to 500 operations. Therefore, if your collection contains more than 500 documents, you may use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead.

---

As a side note, it's worth noting the existence of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

> Template literals are enclosed by the backtick (grave accent)
>   character instead of double or single quotes... and can contain
>   placeholders.